# Plot graph in python with data from file

Tags: python, plot

How can I plot a graph in python taking the values from a file that it just has values? I mean that there are not two columns representing X and Y axis, just values. For example the file contains:

1.5 6 3 0.2 -1.2 4 9 2.34 0.75 1.2....

Thank you

Comment: What kind of plot are you looking for?  Line, bar, scatter, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously you will need to know the structure of the data within the file.  You can read data from a file very easily:

```
with open(filename,"r") as f:
    data = f.read() # or you can use f.readline()
    .....
    #Format the data
```

The matplotlib library is what you want for graphing the data:

http://matplotlib.org/

The documentation is very thorough

You may find this SO answer very useful as well:

[How to plot data with Python from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807726/how-to-plot-data-with-python-from-text-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is formatted as you say in a file with each value separated by a space.

```
1.5 6 3 0.2 -1.2 4 9 2.34 0.75 1.2
```

And assuming that it is representing something like time-series data, then you can import and plot a line graph of that data using something like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "path/to/my_data_file"

# Import data as a list of numbers
with open(filename) as textFile:
    data = textFile.read().split()          # split based on spaces
    data = [float(point) for point in data] # convert strings to floats

# Plot as a time series plot
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Ronny